# get min max values in group of data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In sql server i have a table having more than crores of records like

```
empnos  date
a1  18-Jul-13
a1  18-Jul-13
a1  18-Jul-13
a1  18-Jul-13
a2  18-Jul-13
a2  18-Jul-13
a2  18-Jul-13
a3  18-Jul-13
a1  19-Jul-13
a2  19-Jul-13
a3  19-Jul-13
a1  20-Jul-13
a2  20-Jul-13
a3  20-Jul-13
```

now i want output where it is grouped and each group has min max value so output should be like 1 below

```
EMPNO   DATE
A1  18-Jul-13
A1  20-Jul-13
A2  18-Jul-13
A2  20-Jul-13
A3  18-Jul-13
A3  20-Jul-13
```

Answer (score 4):

> Now there are some changes in requirement i want is in same table i
>   want is top two max values

If you're using SQL-Server you can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT empnos,  
          date,
          rn = row_number() over (partition by empnos order by date desc)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN <= 2
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd0a8/1/0)

If you also want the Min-/Max values per `empnos`, you can use the `OVER` clause:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT empnos,  
          date,
          min = Min(date) over (partition by empnos),
          max = Max(date) over (partition by empnos),
          rn = row_number() over (partition by empnos order by date desc)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN <= 2
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd0a8/3/0)

Comment: This one is for top 2 max values but how about both top 2 min and max value?

Comment: how this give max() and min()? `it give only max and second max values `na?

Comment: @hims056: This is an answer on his changed requirement(_"there are some changes in requirement"_). Have a look at his comment to [Amit Singh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802925/284240).

Comment: WE HAVE SOME RECORDS DAT ARE REPETATIVE LIKE a1 20-Jul-13
a2  20-Jul-13
a3  20-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a2  21-Jul-13
a2  21-Jul-13
a2  21-Jul-13
a3  21-Jul-13 SO THE OUTPUT I WANT IS MAX TWO DATES AND THE REPETATIVE DATE SHOULD BE USED ONLY ONCE LIKE ONLY 21ST JULY AND 20TH JULY DATE

Comment: @TimSchmelter - OP seems not sure what he needs. (in question he wants both min and max but in comment he told he want top 2 max). But can you just update the query in SQLFiddle to get top 2 min and max for me? +1 btw.

Comment: @hims056: I've added another query which combines both, so the top2 rows per `empnos` according to the `date` and the Min/Max values per `empnos`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I was trying to do something like that. Thanks.

Comment: Tim you were right but where der are duplicate date records for same employee nos top two max dates i get duplicate...which i dont want i want distinct top two max dates

Comment: @user2583182: Sorry, id on't understand. `ROW_NUMBER` returns just one record per group whereas `DENSE_RANK` returns all records if there are ties for a rank in the same partition.

Comment: bt im gettin multiple max top date i juzt want top two max date where date should not repeat

Comment: @user2583182: So is `date` the column you want to group by or do you want to group by `empnos` **and** `date`?

Comment: 2012-11-08 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2012-11-06 00:00:00.000 12798
2013-05-27 00:00:00.000 88M73132
2013-05-27 00:00:00.000 88M73132 as u can see 12798 has same date2012-11-06 bt i want it juzt once

Comment: @user2583182: Yes of course because that was your requirement: _"Now there are some changes in requirement i want is in same table i want is top two max values"_. Then change `WHERE RN <= 2` to `WHERE RN = 1`

Comment: c i want rn dats row nos of 1 and 2 dat becums top max two rows bt since der are multiple dates having same value so i get rn two multiple times which i want only 1nce

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33958/discussion-between-user2583182-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select empnos ,  Max(date) from TableName Group by empnos 
Union
Select empnos ,  Min(date) from TableName Group by empnos order by empnos
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa5b6/2)

Comment: thanxs bt now there are some changes in requirement i want is in same table i want is  top two max values

Comment: @user2583182 u r using my sql or sql server

Comment: a1 19-Jul-13
a2  19-Jul-13
a3  19-Jul-13
a1 20-Jul-13
a1 20-Jul-13
a2  20-Jul-13
a3  20-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a1 21-Jul-13
a2  21-Jul-13
a2  21-Jul-13
a2  21-Jul-13
a3  21-Jul-13

Comment: @user2583182 u r using my sql or sql server

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from (
    Select empnos ,  Max(date) dat from TableName Group by empnos 
    Union all
    Select empnos ,  Min(date) dat from TableName Group by empnos 
 ) a 
    order by empnos, dat
```

`union all` or `union` can be used based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t table (
   empnos   char(2)
 , the_date date
);

INSERT INTO @t (empnos, the_date)
  VALUES ('a1', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a1', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a1', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a1', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a2', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a2', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a2', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a3', '18-Jul-13')
       , ('a1', '19-Jul-13')
       , ('a2', '19-Jul-13')
       , ('a3', '19-Jul-13')
       , ('a1', '20-Jul-13')
       , ('a2', '20-Jul-13')
       , ('a3', '20-Jul-13');

SELECT empnos
     , Max(the_date) As the_date
FROM   @t
GROUP
    BY empnos

UNION ALL

SELECT empnos
     , Min(the_date) As the_date
FROM   @t
GROUP
    BY empnos

ORDER
    BY empnos
     , the_date
```

Result:

```
empnos the_date
------ ----------
a1     2013-07-18
a1     2013-07-20
a2     2013-07-18
a2     2013-07-20
a3     2013-07-18
a3     2013-07-20
```